# c# regex groups

Tags: c#, regex

How convert string to groups

STRING:

```
TableStart:Name="valueName";ClassName="valueClassName";MasterDatasource="valueMasterDatasource";Condition="valueCondition";ConditionParams="valueConditionParams";OrderBy="valueOrderBy"
```

OUTPUT GROUPS:

```
Name = "valueName"
ClassName = "valueClassName"
MasterDatasource = "valueMasterDatasource"
Condition = "valueCondition"
ConditionParams = "valueConditionParams"
OrderBy = "valueOrderBy"
```

Regex?

```
TableStart:Name=(?<Name>".*");ClassName=(?<ClassName>".*");MasterDatasource=(?<MasterDatasource>".*");Condition=(?<Condition>".*");ConditionParams=(?<ConditionParams>".*");OrderBy=(?<OrderBy>".*")
```

Comment: And where is your problem? Your regex looks quite OK, what is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this snippet:

```
var s = "TableStart:Name=\"valueName\";ClassName=\"valueClassName\";MasterDatasource=\"valueMas" +
"terDatasource\";Condition=\"valueCondition\";ConditionParams=\"valueConditionParams\"" +
";OrderBy=\"valueOrderBy\"";

var reg = new Regex("TableStart:Name=(?<Name>\".*\");ClassName=(?<ClassName>\".*\");MasterDatasource=(?<Ma" +
"sterDatasource>\".*\");Condition=(?<Condition>\".*\");ConditionParams=(?<ConditionPa" +
"rams>\".*\");OrderBy=(?<OrderBy>\".*\")");

Match match = reg.Match(s);
GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
for (int i = 1; i < groups.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", reg.GroupNameFromNumber(i), groups[i].Value);
}
```

prints:

```
Name = "valueName"
ClassName = "valueClassName"
MasterDatasource = "valueMasterDatasource"
Condition = "valueCondition"
ConditionParams = "valueConditionParams"
OrderBy = "valueOrderBy"
```

**Edit:** or you can use a much concise and shorter regexp

```
var reg = new Regex("\\w+\\=\"\\w+\"");

foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(s))
{
    var values = match.Value.Split('=');
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} = {1}",values[0], values[1]);
}
```

prints the same.

Answer (score 0):

A regex-less alternative:

```
string input = "TableStart:Name=\"valueName\";ClassName=\"valueClassName\";MasterDatasource=\"valueMasterDatasource\";Condition=\"valueCondition\";ConditionParams=\"valueConditionParams\";OrderBy=\"valueOrderBy\"";
input = input.Replace("TableStart:", "");
string[] nameValues = input.Split(';');
foreach (string nameValue in nameValues){
    string[] couple = nameValue.Split('=');
    string name = couple[0];
    string value = couple[1].Trim('"');
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", name, value);
}
```